# Rails extremely slow on simple static render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I'm relatively new to Rails, but decided to develop my new project on this platform. I'm using new Rails 4 framework based on Ruby 2.0 and Unicorn as application server served through Nginx.
After some initial development I deployed my application to Amazon EC2 small server, and was literally shocked by the slow performance, testing it with simple `ab` utility. Giving you more details:

unicorn config file:

```
# config/unicorn.rb
env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development"

worker_processes 1

listen 8080, :backlog => 64

preload_app true

timeout 30

pid "/tmp/unicorn.mysite.pid"


if env == "production"

  working_directory "/mypath/current"

  user 'ubuntu', 'ubuntu'
  shared_path = "/mypath/shared"

  stderr_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
  stdout_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  old_pid = "/tmp/unicorn.mysite.pid.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

end
```

routes.rb:

```
root to: "home#index"
```

home_controller.rb:

```
def index
    render "index", layout: false
end
```

and `index.html.erb` is just mostly static 3kb file

There are no DB queries, Unicorn running in production mode, partials cache enabled in Rails.

`ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://myinstance.amazon.com/` returns like 30-40 requests/per second performance, and average 3-4 seconds response time with 1 unicorn's worker(remember I'm using small 1cpu instance), and even less when increased to four. Strange enough when I tried to test the application on amazon's medium instance, it didnt improve the performance, giving a hint that it's probably limited by disk io. Well, when I replicated the same simple application on PHP and node.js stacks, that I used before, significantly better performance(more requests per second served with much shorter response times) comparing to the above mentioned Rails.
Is it normal for a Rails application? Any hints how to improve performance? Maybe some configuration tweaks? I tried to search, but I see mostly general information about Rails code improvements that do not apply here due to oversimplified example.

**UPDATE #1**
I include pieces of `production.log` on request, they vary from:

```
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.830189 #1852]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for xx.xx.xx.xx at 2013-07-20 13:21:44 +0000
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.831420 #1852]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as */*
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.832519 #1852]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (0.5ms)
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.834213 #1852]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.5ms)
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.834966 #1852]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.835143 #1852]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/index.html.erb (3.2ms)
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.835356 #1852]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

to:

```
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.689225 #1852]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for xx.xx.xx.xx at 2013-07-20 13:21:44 +0000
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.690629 #1852]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as */*
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.716144 #1852]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (24.7ms)
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.718191 #1852]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.7ms)
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.718919 #1852]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.719042 #1852]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/index.html.erb (27.7ms)
I, [2013-07-20T13:21:44.719280 #1852]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 28.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**UPDATE #2**
I tried to make 10000 consequent requests and server simply timed out in the middle

```
ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://myinstance.amazon.com/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking myinstance.amazon.com (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection timed out (110)
Total of 3457 requests completed
```

Comment: Could you include a piece of production.log? (server boot and some requests)

Comment: I added few pieces of production log to the post

Comment: you are running rails in production mode on the server? and priming the app before running `ab`? also `worker_processes 1` means you can only handle 1 request at a time - try bumping to at least 2, you could go higher, but I think recommendation is for 1 per processor - also consider `puma` instead of `unicorn` - see http://blog.wiemann.name/rails-server

Comment: Tried with puma, played a little with threads numbers, generally it gives similar performance to unicorn in single mode. Probably will outperform it on multicore instance with cluster. But single cpu performance is still ashamedly slow, around 40 requests per second. The worst thing is that about 2% of requests are served _after_ 20 seconds! It would translate to lost opportunities and customers in any ecommerce

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is quite expected result. You compare 3 different things: full-featured framework (**Rails**), platform (**Node.js**) and language (**PHP**).

Let's see how we split the response time:

```
[total time] = [web server processing  time] + [framework infrastructure time] 
             + [language interpreter time] + [your app logic time]
```

Of course, in case if your application will do nothing, the last component can be neglected.

When you run **PHP** or **Node.js** application there remain only **2 components** in the sum: `[web server processing  time] + [language interpreter time]`, so it can handle requests very fast. **Rails** adds here the **3d** component `[framework infrastructure time]`.

If your application will start to do something more advanced then time spent in framework and webserver can have less impact on the total time (relatively). Though **JavaScript** will outperform **Ruby** nevertheless.

To be more objective you'd better add something on top of **Node.js** (like Express.js) or **PHP** (like Yii or Zend Framework). Or use something more lightweight instead of **Rails** to process small request much faster (e.g. Sinatra)